# Read Android color resource from a style that references it

Tags: android, kotlin

I have styles defined in my app

```xml
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeA" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color1</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ThemeB" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color2</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I can read one of those colors directly:

```kotlin
Color(context.resources.getColor(R.color.color1))
```

But what I really want is to reference it *through the style*, so that if the style definition changes, the code still loads the right color, something like:

```kotlin
// doesn't work
Color(context.resources.getColor(R.style.ThemeA.colorPrimary))
```

I know I can do this by calling `setTheme(R.style.ThemeA)` and then `getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary)`, but I don't want to do that because I don't want to change all colors for the entire context at once. Different parts of the UI might read different styles *at the same time*.